# Find Index of Array Fails

Tags: lodash

I have an array of components (this.needle) where SOME but not all of them have an existing RMA which is an RMA object inside the component object. I am trying to code a delete of the RMA. The method receives the record so I know obj HAS an rma object.

The needle array is an array of object like these:

```
[
    {
        cmp_auto_key: 3047,
        company_code: "FCAS2",
        condition_code: "AR",
        description: "PUMP, ELECT MOTOR DRIVEN",
        invc_number: "87259",
        msn: '11105",
        rma: {
            contact: "jsmith@co.com",
            disposition: 1,
            id: 714,
            status_id: 3,
            submit_deadline: "2019-11-08 00:00:00"
        }
    },
    {
        cmp_auto_key: 3047,
        company_code: "FCAS2",
        condition_code: "AR",
        description: "PUMP, ELECT MOTOR DRIVEN",
        invc_number: "87259",
        msn: '11111"
    }

]
```

And here is the delete code:

```
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this RMA?')) {
    let id = obj.rma.id;
    let idx = _.findIndex(this.needle, {id: obj.rma.id}); //produces error
    console.log('KILLER', this.needle[idx]);
    this.needle[idx].rma = null;
    console.log('KILLED', this.needle[idx]);
} // end if
```

This code dies on the line indicated because not all element in the array have an RMA object so it returns

> "Cannot set property 'rma' of undefined"

Is there a way to get the findIndex to ignore the record all together if there is no rma object without throwing the exception?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share how your `obj` with `rma` and `needle` looks like?

Comment: Also for deleting a property, shouldn't you use `delete` instead of setting it to null? To add, Add console.log for needle inside if `condition` and same for `rma`

Comment: modified question to include requet

Comment: And rma as well?

Comment: rma is an object inside those components that have an existing RMA

Comment: Two things, It appears like your `this.needle` does not have `id` which is one thing. Second thing, what is your `obj.rma.id`

Comment: obj.rma.id == 714

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200654/discussion-between-irohitbhatia-and-jgravois).